# What type of pattern do the Web User Controls in ASP.NET fall into?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I'm just curious to know what type of pattern do the Web User Controls in ASP.NET fall into?

Comment: Design patterns are specific tools to solve specific problems, not everything is a design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we can talk about a design pattern, I would say that its related to
[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principles

You create a user control when you're trying to group some functionality. Reasons for doing this are:

- To split a page in smaller pieces for simplicity (KISS)
- To avoid repeated logic (DRY)